# Probability theory problem

Tags: probability-theory

A bag contains $5$ white and $5$ black balls. **A** draws $5$ balls retain any that are white and returns any black ones to the bag. **B** then draws $5$ balls, retains any that are white and returns any black ones to the bag. Now there are $6$ balls in the bag. Find the probability **A** drew exactly 2 white balls.

Comment: You mean 'A drew exactly 5 white balls'?

Comment: @Alex Then the answer is 0.

Comment: Or exactly $5$ black balls?

Comment: @Abel: I read: 'A draws 5 balls...find the probability A drew exactly 5 balls' It's 1!)

Comment: @Alex I know, but if you change 'white' for 'black' the question is non-trivial all of a sudden.

Comment: @Abel: I agree, this would mean the probability B drew 4 white and 1 black ball, but the question should be changed accordingly.

Comment: The probability that A drew 5 balls is 100% since the question states: " A draws 5 balls"

Answer (score 0):

OK, I answer the question assuming it said 'A drew exactly 5 black balls'. In this case before B samples from the basket, it hasthe same same composition as before A did his sampling.

Then the question reduces to 'what is the probability B samples 4 white and 1 black balls, since this is the only way it is possible to observe 6 balls after 1 sampling.

This is called Negative Binomial distribution, and the probability of this event is 
$$
P(S) = \frac{\binom{5}{4} \cdot \binom{5}{1}}{\binom{10}{5}}
$$

Comment: Sorry, @Alex, but this is not correct. The correct answer is found after applying Bayes' theorem, but I don't think anyone should give this question a complete answer since it seems to be a verbatim copy of homework and a sloppy one at that.